# React performance during communication with API - 1 call-2s vs 262 calls-max 0.3s

Tags: reactjs, performance, yii2

I am developing React application that communicates with PHP JSON API. And I compare the performance of my application with the performance of the Amazon web page.

My application:

- Browser, web server and PHP server (Yii2 framework) are on the same machine
- React application makes 1 API call, which lasts 2s for downloading 20kb of data (if data about is several bytes, then 'waiting (TTFB)' is almost 2s, and 'Content download' is 0.0001s; if data is about 20kb, then 'waiting (TTBF)' is about 0.4s, and 'Content download' is 1.4s).
- Page load is completed within 3s, that is long time and experience is bad.

Amazon web page:

- Server is remote, of course.
- Page load makes around 262 calls, each of them lasts no more than 0.3s, many of them less.
- Page load is completed within 1.5s, experience is perfect.

How to understand this difference in performance. Can I blame my PHP server for bad configuration of insufficient resources? My development machine has 4GHz CPU with 8 virtual cores, 16GB RAB, very low resources are utilized by background services. Even the simples response from PHP server with 2 bytes takes almost 2 seconds to complete. Is this configuration issue of bad programming failure?

Answer (score 1):

It could be bad configuration but I'd start by checking the debugger tool that comes with Yii and see how much time is spent on each operation to know if there is anything wrong with code or database queries first. Performance is not only related to machine resources. There is advanced optimization techniques, caching, load balancing, use of CDN, ... But 3s is too long anyway and requires investigation to figure out where it is spent.